# passing hidden field values to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

is it possible to get the value of the hidden field that is defined in the gridview to the javascript function so I have a gridview that has a linked button defined in it. If the user clicks on the link button, I am invoking a javascript function. I want the hidden field values in the javascript function.

also, I was wondering if it is possible to pass multiple values in one hiden field and then split them later in the javascript function.

any help will be appreciated. I don't want to go to code behind and then invoke the javascript function from there.

Comment: you can possibly look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789670/get-grid-view-hidden-field-value-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The first task is to determine a "suitable selector" for the hidden fields - this can be the ID (get via [`control.ClientID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)) of each individual hidden field or a more general selector like "all hidden fields in a particular div (with a particular ID)". Use `<%= .. %>` (or `<%@ .. %>` in a data-binding context) to put this information into the actual HTML response.

The exact approach will vary - basically, whichever is easiest - for the task.

Then, *using your favorite library or advanced browser with applicable selector support* (it is easier to find good libraries)<sup>1</sup>, use the given selector. In jQuery, this might be similar to the following, where `fn` is the function to process all the values. The actual selector is the stuff in quotes:

```
fn(jQuery("#clientIdOfGridView input[type='hidden']"))
```

Which might be written in ASP.NET, which is how the appropriate element ID is injected:

```
fn(jQuery("#<%= gridView.ClientID %> input[type='hidden']"))
```

These will both pass a [jQuery object](http://jquery.org) *representing* the hidden field elements to the function. Then use `val()` and/or `each()` (see the jQuery documentation and other SO questions) for usage.

There are many questions relating to just jQuery and "selecting values", so this is entire "answer" is really to provide a lead on how to get started - Happy coding :)

---

<sup>1</sup> While this can be done manually with "old-school" finding a element by ID and DOM traversal, I find it a waste of my time to do such a task manually. I like jQuery but there are alternatives. Use the existing wheels; they roll relatively fast.

Comment: I am not using jquery in my application. do you have a javascript solution.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript (there are also lighter-weight selector libraries available; ask Mr. Google). If you prefer to do it by hand, **then learn to do it by hand**. That is, research that specific task, now that you know what it is. (Task: "Find hidden fields which are a descendants of a particular DOM element according to a particular structure.")

Answer (score 0):

you can specify as much values in one value-attribute of a hidden field as you like. You must make sure use a delimiter like "," or "#" which you can use in your function to split the string of values according to your needs.